# How to prevent other classes to create instance of one class?

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I have case which consists of three classes namely SourceFactory, Source, and SourceTypeI. I want to create instance of SourceTypeI only in SourceFactory. In other words, other than SourceFactory, no class can create instance of SourceTypeI. How can I prevent other classes can create SourceTypeI?

Expected usage;

```
  SourceFactory sF = new SourceFactory();
  Source source = sF.createSource();

  // from there, I should reach methods of SourceTypeI via source
  source.whoIs();
```

Classes

```
  |-------------|           |-----------------------|
  |SourceTypeI  |           |SourceFactory          |
  |-------------|           |-----------------------|
  |+whoIs():void|           |+createSource():Source |
  |             |           |                       |
  |-------------|           |-----------------------|

  |-----------------------------|
  |    Source                   | <- Source cannot be instantiated, it is used just a 
  |-----------------------------|    for referencing instance of SourceTypeI 
  |                             |
  |-----------------------------|
```

Comment: Is it Source (as the code shows) or SourceTypeI (as the text says) that is to be restricted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can put `SourceFactory` and `SourceTypeI` in the same package. Then make `SourceTypeI` final. Next give `SourceTypeI` package level (default) constructors.

```
SourceTypeI() { // <-- not public, not private, not protected.
  super();
}
```

Then don't put "any other class(es)" in that package.

Comment: What should I in other two classes so that I can reach SourceTypeI methods via Source class? Or Should I need to write something?

Comment: @Zmavus Make `SourceTypeI` methods public, just not the constructor!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for changing the names.

```
public interface Restricted { // Source
    public int getX();
}

public class Restrict {  // SourceFactory
    private class RestrictedImpl implements Restricted {
        public int getX(){ return 42; }
    }

    public Restricted createRestricted(){
        return new RestrictedImpl();
    }
}

Restrict restrict = new Restrict();
Restricted restricted1 = restrict.createRestricted();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can `RestrictedImp` class have own file because `RestrictedImpTypeII` may need to be implemented. If I put those two class in Restrict, the overall code quality will decrease.

Comment: There's a limit to the restriction of visibility you can achieve with Java. Elliots answer mentioning the package may be the way you'll have to go. - OTOH, you can wrap another implementation of Source/Restricted into another wrapper, and still have a single Factory delegating the createXyz to the individual wrapper, so clients won't suffer.

Comment: Are there any thing like  C++ `friend` keyword in java? May be, I can achieve with friend methods of class.